# Photoshop scripting - trying to reference an UI element created in a funtion that is in a different file

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm creating a script where a user must select from several dropdown lists in order to name their image. Since each row in the ui is the same and function the same (It contains a dropdown list, a selection box to enable editing the list, an edit text box and add/edit/remove buttons), I've created a function to add these ui elements instead of writing each one out.  This function is also in a separate file.  Everything works up until this point.  What I now need to do is take whatever the user selected in the dropdown lists and create a file name from it. However, I cannot access the list. I guess because the function is last bit that is called.

I created a function that constructs the file name.  I then tried to call the dropdown list in different locations and in different ways.

```
var dlg = new Window('dialog', 'Material to Library');

    //Material category panel, used to select which material dialogue option appears
    dlg.grp0 = dlg.add('group');
        dlg.grp0.addCatPnl = dlg.grp0.add('panel', [10, 110, 705, 170], 'Assign a type of material');
            panelOption(0, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatTitle, 'Material Category:', dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCat, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatAddBox, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatNew, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatEditText, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatAddButt, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatEdtButt, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl.matCatRmvButt, dlg.grp0.addCatPnl, 15, 40, false);

    //2)Create a panel for the option
    dlg.swap = dlg.add ('group');
    dlg.swap.visible = true;
    dlg.swap.orientation = 'stack';

        //panel swaps in
        dlg.swap.asgnPnlV = dlg.swap.add('panel', [10, 200, 705, 450], 'Assign material name');
            dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.visible = false;
            var ddlName = dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfg;
            panelOption(1, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgTitle, 'Manufacturer:', dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfg, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgAddBox, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgNew, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgEditText, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgAddButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgEdtButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfgRmvButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, 15, 40, true);
            panelOption(1, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesTitle, 'Species', dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpecies, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesAddBox, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesNew, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesEditText, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesAddButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesEdtButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpeciesRmvButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, 50, 75, true);
            panelOption(1, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutTitle, 'Cut', dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCut, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutsAddBox, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutNew, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutEditText, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutAddButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutEdtButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCutRmvButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, 85, 110, true);
            panelOption(1, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainTitle, 'Stain', dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStain, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainAddBox, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainNew, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainEditText, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainAddButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainEdtButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStainRmvButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, 120, 145, false);
            panelOption(1, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapTitle, 'Map', dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMap, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapAddBox, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapNew, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapEditText, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapAddButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapEdtButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMapRmvButt, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, 155, 180, false);
            //This one works(below), but this is not what I want
            //materialName(dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMatName, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, 'sel1', 'sel2', 'sel3', 'sel4', 'sel5');
            //This one (below) is what I actually want Error 21, undefined is not an object line 25....
            materialName(dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMatName, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMfg.selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerSpecies.selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerCut.selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerStain.selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMap.selection);  

        //Other panels to swap in

    ////

dlg.show();

    ////

    function panelOption(panelPosition, title, titleText, name, nameAddbox, nameNew, nameEditText, nameAddButt, nameEdtButt, nameRmvButt, pnlNm, x1, x2, isUpperCase){
        var listArray = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'veneer'];
        title = pnlNm.add('StaticText', [15, x1, 110, x2], titleText.toString());
        name = pnlNm.add('DropDownList', [120, x1, 230, x2], listArray);
        nameAddbox = pnlNm.add('checkbox', [240, x1, 260, x2], 'Edit List');
            nameAddbox.value = false;           
        nameNew = pnlNm.add('StaticText', [330, x1, 360, x2], 'New:');
        nameEditText = pnlNm.add('EditText', [360, x1, 480, x2],);
            nameEditText.enabled = false;
        nameAddButt = pnlNm.add('button', [490, x1, 545, x2], ' add ');
            nameAddButt.enabled = false;
        nameEdtButt = pnlNm.add('button', [555, x1, 610, x2], 'edit');
            nameEdtButt.enabled = false;
        nameRmvButt = pnlNm.add('button', [620, x1, 675, x2], 'remove');
            nameRmvButt.enabled = false;

        if (panelPosition == 0){
            name.onChange = function(){
                var x = name.selection;
                switch (x.toString()){
                case 'veneer':
                    dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.visible = true;
                    dlg.swap.asgnPnlSS.visible = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.visible = false;  
                }
            }
        }
    }

function materialName(matName, pnlNm, nom1, nom2, nom3, nom4, nom5){
    var temp = 'material name here build as it goes';
    var nomenclature1 = nom1;
    var nomenclature2 = nom2;
    var nomenclature3 = nom3;
    var nomenclature4 = nom4;
    var nomenclature5 = nom5;

    var temp = nomenclature1 + '_' + nomenclature2 + '_' + nomenclature3 + '_' + nomenclature4 + '_' + nomenclature5;
    matName = pnlNm.add('StaticText', [15, 205, 310, 230], temp);

    if (pnlNm.visible == true){
        dlg.findElement ('veneerMfg').onChange = function() {
            //var nomenclature1 = Nom1.selection;
            //return nomenclature1;
            alert ('found element');
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is the the name.selection to be one of the values in the dropdown list that was selected by the user.
Whenever I call the name.selection element that was created with the function it gives be 'undefined'.  I tried dlg.findElement ('veneerMfg') this gave me 'null', which I am guessing it means it found the element, but I need to be able to find it when the user changes the selection in the dropdown box.

Comment: Could you please update you question with a shorter code sample that'd reflect your problem? At the moment it doesn't run because there're too much dependencies from other parts or code or external files and it's not easy to dig through it.

Comment: I sorted through it and removed the dependencies.  I'm not sure if I can make it much shorter without sifting through it more carefully, let me know if its still too much and I'll keep at.

Comment: lines 22-25 along with its function is where I'm having the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to access the dropdowns would be via `children` of your `dlg.swap.asgnPnlV` panel, something like this:

```
var myButton = dlg.add('button',undefined,'Test');

myButton.onClick = function() {
    var k = 1; // there're 40 children, each 8th is the dropdown, starting from index 1
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children.length; i++) {
     // add only every 8th element
     if ((i-k)%8 == 0) { 
        names.push(dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children[i].selection)
     }
    }
    alert(names);
}
```

[image]

So your function would look something like this:

```
materialName(dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMatName, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children[1].selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children[9].selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children[17].selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children[25].selection, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.children[33].selection);
```

This is however not very versatile. Even better would be adding all those panel in a loop, this way it's possible to modify my `names` object on the fly without asking for all the children. Note the closure I used to make sure that all dropdowns will change `names` properly.

```
var panelData = [
{
    name: 'Manufacturer',
    list: ['m1', 'm2', 'm3'],
    coords: [15, 40]
},
{
    name: 'Species',
    list: ['s1', 's2'],
    coords: [50, 75]
},
{
    name: 'Cut',
    list: ['cut1', 'cut2', 'cut3', 'cut4', 'cut5'],
    coords: [85, 110]
},
{
    name: 'Stain',
    list: ['stain1', 'stain2', 'stain3', 'stain4'],
    coords: [120, 145]
},
{
    name: 'Map',
    list: ['map1', 'map2', 'map3', 'map4', 'map5', 'map6'],
    coords: [155, 180]
}];

var mygroup;
var names = {};

for (var i = 0; i < panelData.length; i++)
{
    (function(item)
    {
        var mygroup = dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.add('group', [15, item.coords[0], 410, item.coords[1]]);
        mygroup.add('statictext', [0, 0, 110, 20], item.name);
        var myDropDown = mygroup.add('DropDownList', [110, 0, 230, 20], item.list);
        myDropDown.onChange = function()
        {
            names[item.name] = String(this.selection)
        }
    })(panelData[i])
}

var myB = dlg.add('button', undefined, 'Test');

myB.onClick = function()
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(names));
}
```

[image]

so your function would look like this:

```
materialName(dlg.swap.asgnPnlV.veneerMatName, dlg.swap.asgnPnlV, names['Manufacturer'], names['Species'], names['Cut'], names['Stain'], names['Map']);
```

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thank you!  I've tried the fist one worked perfectly.  I'll have to take more time on the second option.  I have 6 more panels that swap out and the list is created and referenced from a text file.  Sure looks cleaner though.

Comment: Great to hear it worked! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so others cluld easily find it :)

Comment: Second example worked too, I'm just having some trouble getting everything to work properly because I've never worked with function expression?? (is that what that's called??).  I'm not really sure why sometimes you use item.whatever but for the list selection you use this.selection.

Comment: If you're getting a value from somewhere, you can get it by from  `dropdownName.selection`, but inside the dropdown onChange function, the same `dropdownName` cane be referenced as `this`. In the particular case of the function I wrote, `this.selection` and `dropdownName.selection` is the same thing